# ADAL4J, promptbehavior support missing

Tags: adal

is it correct that the current impl. of the ADAL4J does not provide any support for promptbehavior in regards to the acquireToken implementation ?

if not, can I somehow force it to show the idp's "secure login container" :) ?

regards Allan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, as of today ADAL for Java implements only server to server flows which do not include authentication UX.
HTH
V.

Comment: well Vittorio then you know what todo the next couple of days :).